# Auto close connection when openvpn lose connection

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn

Is there a way to disable/close connection automatically if OpenVPN lose the VPN connection?

I'm currently using Debian.

Answer (score 3):

This is from Arch Linux wiki, but it should be applicable to all other distributions.

[Prevent leaks if VPN goes down](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#Prevent_leaks_if_vpn_goes_down)

To get more info on what UFW (Uncomplicated FireWall, used in above article) is, see:

[UFW@Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

[UFW@Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uncomplicated_Firewall)